# Cannot find an ADB driver for my android phone

Tags: android, adb

I am just a newbie in developing apps for Android devices and I have an Android Phone from Cherry Mobile called Superion Radar.

I wanted to run my android projects in this device but the problem is I can't seem to find any OEM Drivers for it and I don't know where else to look for OEM USB drivers for it.

Please help. Cherry Mobile is a Filipino Brand so I think it would be better if Filipino Android Developers can answer but I will appreciate all the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the usual case for most of the Chinese and Indian handset's. The manufacturer rarely provides adb drivers. You can try using [AdbDriverInstaller.exe](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/). It will work on most of the phones but if the driver is available from official sources like OEM then I recommend to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the `adb` driver that comes with the android SDK? I have found that manually installing that though device manager is a much better solution that does not require third party programs to be installed on my machine.

```
/path/to/android-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver
```

Open your device manager, and find the unknown device - > right click it and click `Update Driver Software`.

`Browse my ...` -> `Let me pick ...` -> `Next` -> `Have Disk` -> `Browse`

In this window, browse to the aforementioned usb driver path in the sdk, in this directory you should see a `.inf` file. Double clicking this will install the google adb driver for this device.