# Manufacturer does not provide an ADB driver for my android phone

Tags: android, adb

the manufacturer has no driver for my phone model (micromax bharat 2 / Q402) on the website. can I install some other phone's driver? any way to use my phone to test apps?

Answer (score 0):

the first answer here [Cannot find an OEM USB driver for my android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406510/cannot-find-an-oem-usb-driver-for-my-android-phone) helped me. This guy literally saved me from a fatal heart attack. And a brain stroke. Thanks ["Illegal Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833783/illegal-argument)